# Prevent loss of preceeding zeroes in [MEMNO] value when querying?

Tags: c#, sql, odbc, database-connection, ibm-midrange

I have several SQL statements I'm using in an application. I've noticed that when certain Member Numbers are returning, such as `012345`, they are returning as `12345`. This number is used to assist with filenaming conventions and by some other criteria is required to be in a 6 digit format to process files correctly.

Can anyone assist me with this? The cut-off comes from querying an IBM AS400 system. Someone suggested using the DIGITS( ) function, but I have not yet got it to work with the below example query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DIGITS(a.memno), 
a.name, 
a.addr1, 
a.addr2, 
a.city, 
a.state, 
a.zip, 
a.sex, 
a.lname, 
a.ssan, 
b.addr1 as old_addr1, 
b.addr2 as old_addr2, 
b.city as old_city, 
b.state as old_state, 
b.zip as old_zip, 
'P' as SYS 
FROM Lib1.Table1 a, Lib1.Table2 b 
WHERE a.memno = b.memno and 
      b.groupid = 'P2' and  
      b.type = 'B' and  
      b.rcchg <> 'N' and  
      b.datec = 20140107  
      AND (UPPER(a.addr1) <> UPPER(b.addr1) or UPPER(a.addr2) <> UPPER(b.addr2) or UPPER(a.city) <> UPPER(b.city) or UPPER(a.state) <> UPPER(b.state) or UPPER(a.zip) <> UPPER(b.zip)) 
UNION SELECT DISTINCT 
DIGITS(a.memno), 
a.name, 
a.addr1, 
a.addr2, 
a.city, 
a.state, 
a.zip, 
a.sex, 
a.lname, 
a.ssan, 
b.addr1 as old_addr1, 
b.addr2 as old_addr2, 
b.city as old_city, 
b.state as old_state, 
b.zip as old_zip, 
'N' as SYS 
FROM Lib2.Table1 a, Lib2.Table2 b 
WHERE a.memno = b.memno and  
      b.groupid = 'N2' and  
      b.type = 'B' and  
      b.rcchg <> 'N' and  
      b.datec = 20140107 AND (UPPER(a.addr1) <> UPPER(b.addr1) or UPPER(a.addr2) <> UPPER(b.addr2) or UPPER(a.city) <> UPPER(b.city) or UPPER(a.state) <> UPPER(b.state) or UPPER(a.zip) <> UPPER(b.zip)) 
ORDER BY sys, memno asc
```

When I run this query on the AS400, it works exactly as expected. However, when I run it through my data connection in Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2012, I receive:

```
Error Source: CWBODBC.DLL
Error Message: ERROR [Hy000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0208 - ORDER BY column MEMNO or expression not in result table.
```

This query is sent through my C# application using an ODBC Command on an ODBC Connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the column number:

```
ORDER BY 16, 1 asc
```

**EDIT**: Add supporting background information.

The first column is unnamed, because it is the result of a function.

The final table's first column is unnamed because column1 in the first `SELECT` is unnamed.
Because the column is unnamed, it cannot be included in an `ORDER BY`.

So in addition to ORDER BY 1 asc, you could alter the first SELECT to be something like

`SELECT DISTINCT DIGITS(a.memno) as memno, 
...
ORDER BY sys, memno`

By giving the column a name in the first SELECT, the result table column has a name.

[IBM DB2 for i SQL reference 7.1 ORDER BY](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzorderby.htm)

Comment: See my edit.  Not sure how you ran the SQL on the IBM i side, or what version of DB2 for I you're running, or what version of the ODBC driver you're using.  Clearly there's a difference between them.

Comment: Ok, thanks Buck! This worked, but I also noticed that Server Explorer kept trying to rename my `DIGITS(a.memno)` as Expr1, so by setting it as `DIGITS(a.memno) as memno`, everything is running correctly even with `ORDER BY sys, memno asc`. Thanks again for the help!